# How can I call other method in the same class on php?

Tags: php, laravel-4, tcpdf

Good Day,

Im trying to modify my TCPDF header by creating a custom method within the laravel 4 controller, heres my code:

```
<?php 

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //5minutes


class PdfController extends BaseController
{

public function Header() {
    // Logo
    $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
    $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< TCPDF Example 003 >>', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
}


public function poPdf()
{


    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 048');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

 // set default header data
 $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 048', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, 'Example of HTML tables', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// $all = Session::all();
$data = Session::get('products');

// dd($data);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// NON-BREAKING TABLE (nobr="true")

$tbl = <<<EOD
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
<thead>
<tr>
<td width="30px;">Id</td>
<td width="130px;">Name</td>
<td width="220px;">Description</td>
<td width="80px;">Quantity</td>
<td width="80px;">Price</td>
<td width="80px;">Subtotal</td>
</tr>
<thead>
$data
</table>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_048.pdf', 'I');


}
}
```

my question how can I set my header into the value of the Header method that I defined earlier.

like `$pdf->SetHeaderData(public function Header());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing you should do is learn a bit more about inheritance in PHP, because most of the issues with your sample code are related to a misunderstanding about which class is extending which other class. If you do a search on "object inheritance in PHP" you will find an abundance of great articles.

Now, on to the actual code...

I can see that you have extended `BaseController`. Normally you would extend this class if you were implementing a Controller class that was going to process the incoming web requests. Laravel 4 implements a fairly straightforward controller/action approach to URIs. For example, you might implement a controller called `WidgetController` (which would extend `BaseController`) that had a `getIndex` method, which would be called when you hit the `/widget` URI. Additionally, you could implement a `getDetail` method, which would be displayed when the `/widget/detail` URI was hit.

The methods you have in your sample code do not appear to fit this approach, so I'm guessing that class is **not** an actual Controller class, therefore you do not need to extend `BaseController`.

As far as TCPDF is concerned, there are generally two ways to use it. One way is to simply create an instance of it, as you have done in your sample code, and start calling its methods. The other way is to *extend* TCPDF and then create an instance of that class. If you do that, you can then override certain methods, such as the `Header()` method, which is called each time TCPDF adds a new page. However, implementing the `Header()` method when you are using the first approach (ie. just using an instance of TCPDF directly) is not going to achieve anything, as it won't be automatically called by anything. If you have a closer look at example 3 in the TCPDF package you will see that the author creates a class called `MYPDF`, which extends (or inherits from) `TCPDF` and then works with an instance of `MYPDF`. You have missed this key point in your sample code, which inherits from Laravel's `BaseController` instead of `TCPDF`.

Given that nothing in your header appears to be dynamic, then you could stick with the the approach you are using (ie. working with an instance of the `TCPDF` class) and simply call `$pdf->setHeaderData()`, which will allow you to set an image and text that TCPDF will render in the header on each page.

Alternatively, if your code really isn't a Controller, then you could `extend TCPDF` instead of extending `BaseController` and then your `Header()` method will be called automatically.

I just realised that the last two paragraphs above are probably all I needed to write, but hopefully your or somebody else will find the extra info helpful. :-)

Comment: Hi @JamesG Thank you very much for your very Informative answer, actually I really did not understand well about object inheritance and I dont even knew that that was the word for it. I really appreciate your answer! again Thank you Very much! and Have a Good day!

Comment: Actually I already render a pdf file using TCPDF but I didnt use the "extend class or something" because I have no Idea on how to implement it! instead I did just replace the parameters of the built in methods on TCPDF by manually calling its instance "tcpdf = new TCPDF("..."); Which I recently just found out.

Comment: Good luck with your project and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Just call another method (dohhh) `$this->Header()` ...

Comment: hi @Andrey! Im sorry for this rubbish question but, I already tried your answer and it redirects me to 404 page.. Im not really good at this so please bare with me.. anyways Thank you for trying to help :) Good day!

Comment: Hey, i dunno why you're getting 404, so, try display errors be adding: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` after max_execution_time ini_set.

Comment: I think its because of `$this` Ill try to figure this out :)

Comment: Isn't because `$this`, $this represent class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like it was said, you call other methods of same function with $this. Maybe you forgot to return it:

```
return $this->otherMethod();
```